# Инициализация дин. массива

Tags: c++

Добрый день! 
Есть проблема с выделением памяти под дин.массив: **WBWway;

```
char **WBWay;//ГЛОБАЛЬНАЯ переменная

int M::init_WB_path(char *l, char **way){
    way=new char *[361];
    for(int i=0;i<361;i++)
        way[i]=new char [33];
    // .... работаем с way

    return Im(way[0]);
}
void Menu::antyheroy_part(){
    My=fun(init_WB_path("Images/AntyHerroy/Wbox/", WBWay),point_out,point_out);
....}
```

Нужно выделить память под WBWay... Под way всё выделяется и всё хорошо, но когда метод init_WB_path заканчивает свою работу WBWay не имеет выделенной памяти... Как выделить память под эту переменную используя другой метод?

Comment: А что мешает скопировать значение way в WBWay (сам адрес)?

Comment: Ну, там эта операция выполняется кучу раз, есть много двум.дин массивов... Я передаю в метод путь и массив, а метод должен универсально для всех массивов выделять память и сохранять в них пути....

Comment: А почему так не работает. По сути **way содержит адрес WEWay. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так чтоль

```
int M::init_WB_path(char *l, char ***way){
    *way=new char *[361];
    for(int i=0;i<361;i++)
        (*way)[i]=new char [33];
    // .... работаем с way

    return Im((*way)[0]);
}
void Menu::antyheroy_part(){
    My=fun(init_WB_path("Images/AntyHerroy/Wbox/", &WBWay),point_out,point_out);
....}
```

Comment: ОНО САМОЕ!!! СПАСИБО!